# Color datapoints individually

Tags: plot, octave

Is it possible to color datapoints individually with a single plot command like

```
plot(X,'color',colors);
```

Or do I need a loop for that:

```
for k=1:length(X)
    plot(k,X,'.','color',colors(k,:));
    hold on
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "scatter". You can specify the color as RGB values or index into a colormap. One example

```
x = randn (100, 1);
y = randn (100, 1);
c = randi (20, 100, 1);
scatter(x, y, 10, c, ".")
```